# SEDE refresh didn't happen this Sunday

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

The Stack Exchange Data Explorer is updated every Sunday morning; the first sites are already finished by 3am UTC. However, today this doesn't seem to happen; all I can find is [posts from May 30th and older](https://data.stackexchange.com/apple/query/1418484).

Comment: The data explorer itself tells us that this hasn't happened. Navigating to the [front page](https://data.stackexchange.com/), it says "Data updated May 30 at 10:57"

Comment: Might they be waiting until Microsoft gives feedback analysis after the [failover](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364838/planned-maintenance-scheduled-for-friday-june-4-2021-at-1200am-utc-thursday) data is looked at, I wonder.

Comment: All databases are 8 days old: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1239509/status-of-the-sede-refresh-on-sunday-0300-utc  the good news is that failure of the job should put a mail into the SRE mailbox and I assume they attend to that when their Monday starts. And what a Monday it would be

Comment: Let me poke it to see what happened

Comment: Make sure your stick isn't too sharp @Taryn

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Thanks for the report. There was a permissions issue which resulted in the failure, which should hopefully be resolved.

I kicked off the refresh and it's in the process of running. It normally takes about 8 hours to run, so it will be a little bit before everything is up to date.

Comment: Hmm, you might want to revisit the permissions you have set/revoked. It looks like the job didn't start at 03:00 UTC: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1239509/status-of-the-sede-refresh-on-sunday-0300-utc?cachebreaker=20210613119

Comment: @rene Permissions are fine, it looks like the job just didn't start. It have kicked it off and I'll investigate a little more tomorrow.

Comment: It is indeed on its way now: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1239509/status-of-the-sede-refresh-on-sunday-0300-utc?cachebreaker=20210613119  Thanks for looking into this on your Sunday!