# The SEDE refresh job didn't start

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

Normally, at 03:00 UTC each Sunday the Stack Exchange Data Explorer is being refreshed with the weekly full backup from all sites.

I have [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackapps/query/1239509/status-of-the-sede-refresh-on-sunday-0300-utc) to check on the status of the refresh as it takes 6 to 8 hours to complete. The current output at 10:50 UTC is

[image]

which makes me believe the job didn't start at all.

This is similar to [SEDE refresh didn't happen this Sunday](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366190/sede-refresh-didnt-happen-this-sunday).

I know an [e-mail will be sent to the SRE mailbox in case the job fails](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310219/158100)  but I'm not sure if an e-mail is sent if the job doesn't start at all.

Can you look into what caused the failure to start and while you're at it, start the job manually for us?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The job did kick off but it failed immediately. I made a quick change to the procedure to bypass the failed query to allow the refresh to continue. I've kicked off the process and the refresh has started again.

I suspect there might be something in the latest patch of SQL Server that impacted this, as we just pushed the latest patch this week, but that's a future me problem (aka a tomorrow problem).

Thanks for the report.