# SEDE refresh triggered multiple times today

Tags: bug, data-explorer

As we all know, SEDE is refreshed every Sunday morning, but immediately after it finished (Stack Overflow is the last site, always somewhere before noon UTC), it seems to have triggered a new refresh cycle, as [this query shows](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1682315?Seed=2):

[image]

(Solana is the [newest site](https://stackexchange.com/sites#newest) and hence the first one to be refreshed).

This query just lists the creation date of the database, but I spot checked a few other things (e.g. what time was the most recent post created) and that's consistent.

While it's nice to have a continually refreshing SEDE, I doubt this is intentional, and it would require me and some others to rewrite a couple of cross-database queries to filter out the [temporary databases we can't access](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309917/295232).

Now that we're at Sunday evening (UTC), the refresh cycle seems to have triggered *another* time.

Comment: Oh that is fun: We now have two Temp databases: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUQ0L.png ... So ...  either a restore now goes twice as fast ... or restore tasks are spawning out of control. In the next run we have 4 temp databases ....

Comment: Had to fix my status query as well: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1239509/status-of-the-sede-refresh-on-sunday-0300-utc?cachebreaker=5667&bypassCache=true  it didn't like having two temp databases.

Comment: Things appear to go downhill since bluefeet left. Or more likely, that's why she couldn't stay in the first place.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard I do miss bluefeet as well but I don't think it is fair to attribute the current problems to Taryn leaving the team. Aaron did promise to look into better error handling for failing SEDE tasks. I think this is a case where his automation couldn't handle success ....

Comment: @rene nah, it's just nostalgic rant, Aaron is awesome.

Comment: Oops, it did it again!  evidence: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHUVJ.png

Comment: When the refresh process doesn't run, [you complain](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/366190/348196); so, it goes over the top and runs multiple times, and you still complain. I have to say, you're very hard to please, @Glorfindel :-P

Comment: Looks like that without a [tag:status-review] it's below SE radar.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard at least it stopped refreshing later on Monday. Mabye it ends up as [status-norepro] ...

Comment: No-repro doesn't fit because it clearly happened. Ideally, they'd look into what happened, do something to prevent it in the future, and then it can get the good old [tag:status-completed]. ;)